# Is it unhealthy to to go from resting to exercise several times a day?

Tags: exercise

I think I heard somewhere that it is bad for your body if you constantly go from resting to active by doing some sort of intense exercise straight before and after resting (for example, on the couch relaxing, jumping up and doing 20 or so pushups, going back to sit down). Is this true? If I aimed to do 100 pushups a day and spread it out throughout the day in sets of 20 as I mentioned earlier, is it bad for me? Should I instead try to do it all in one session?

Edit: In terms of 'unhealthy' I meant weight gain.

Comment: What's the question? You're worried about gaining weight if you do multiple short workout sessions per day?

Comment: @Alec Yeah, I thought I heard something like that.

Comment: IMO it's imortant to note that, when you spread the workouts like that, you are significantly changing the resting period between the sets.  E.g. 100 straight pushup is different workout than pushups of 20 wide spread in the day.  Doing straight 100 pushups with no rest could be useful for marathon-like training.  If your goal is maximum strength, then you should add extra weight, such that you fail by the 5th to 8th (max) repetition.   Plus, depending on the workout, sometimes, not warming up has increased injury risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gaining weight is not *directly* related; you will gain weight only if you eat more than you burn.

The reason many don't recommend jumping straight into a strong workout, without warming up first, is because they are afraid of injury.  If you are afraid of being injured, or actually get injured, this will limit your ability in properly performing heavy weight training, which will *indirectly* slow your progress.